# htaccess rename index.php to show as friendly name in URL for SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess

folder structure is like so:

- domain
- ```
   -->folder
  ```
- ```
      -->subfolder
  ```
- ```
          -->index.php
  ```
- ```
          -->another-file.php
  ```

What I want is when I go to `/folder/subfolder` which loads index.php by default, instead will show **/folder/subfolder/more-readable-name-of-my-choosing** in the URL.

I have tried doing things like:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/index.php  /folder/subfolder/more-readable-name-of-my-choosing
```

but I haven't quite figured out the correct pattern yet.

Alternatively, I can rename the index file to `more-readable-name-of-my-choosing.php`, then I would need to figure out how to redirect to that when I go to `/folder/subfolder/` without blocking me from getting to my other files in the subfolder